# Compile error when building qt 5.7 on Windows with msvc 2013

Tags: c++, qt, templates, c++11

When I try to build the source code of Qt 5.7, I am getting the following compile error

> qnode_p.h(108): error C2955:
>   'Qt3DCore::QNodePrivate::DestructionFunction' : use of alias template
>   requires template argument list
>
> qnode_p.h(105) : see declaration of
>   'Qt3DCore::QNodePrivate::DestructionFunction' qscene.cpp
>
> qnode_p.h(108) : error C2955: 'Qt3DCore::QNodePrivate::DestructionFun
>   ction' : use of alias template requires template argument list
>
> qnode_p.h(105) : see declaration of
>   'Qt3DCore::QNodePrivate::DestructionFunction' Generating Code

It is error C2955 use of alias template requires template argument list.

The source code that is causing the problem is below

```
class QT3DCORE_PRIVATE_EXPORT QNodePrivate : public QObjectPrivate, public    QObservableInterface
{
    public:
   QNodePrivate();
   ~QNodePrivate();
...
   template<typename Caller, typename NodeType>
   using DestructionFunction = void (Caller::*)(NodeType *);

   template<typename Caller, typename NodeType, typename PropertyType>
   void registerDestructionHelper(NodeType *, DestructionFunction<Caller, NodeType>, PropertyType);

   template<typename Caller, typename NodeType>
   void registerDestructionHelper(NodeType *node, DestructionFunction<Caller, NodeType> func, NodeType *&)
   {
      // If the node is destoyed, we make sure not to keep a dangling pointer to it
      auto f = std::bind(func, static_cast<Caller *>(q_func()), nullptr);
      m_destructionConnections.insert(node, QObject::connect(node, &QNode::nodeDestroyed, f));
   }

   template<typename Caller, typename NodeType>
   void registerDestructionHelper(NodeType *node, DestructionFunction<Caller, NodeType> func, QVector<NodeType*> &)
   {
      // If the node is destoyed, we make sure not to keep a dangling pointer to it
      auto f = std::bind(func, static_cast<Caller *>(q_func()), node);
      m_destructionConnections.insert(node, QObject::connect(node, &QNode::nodeDestroyed, f));
   }

   //....
}
```

line 105 is using

```
DestructionFunction = void (Caller::*)(NodeType *);
```

line 108 is

```
void registerDestructionHelper(NodeType *, DestructionFunction<Caller, NodeType>, PropertyType);
```

From what I read about C++11 this should compile ok but for some reason vs 2013 gives the above error.

Comment: I will edit your question. But for future posts, only add the meaningful part of the error.

Comment: Building Qt yourself is not recommended for newbies.

Comment: Qt 5.7 requires a modern compiler with *good* C++11/14 support (which VS2013 is not). Try again with VS2015 update 3 :-)

Comment: @ddriver I don't see why not. It's not that complicated and building all of your application and dependent libraries with *the same* compiler is a *good* thing (prevents some bugs).

Comment: There are prebuilt releases for MSVC2013 and MSVC2015. So it should work. There is little point in building it yourself - it takes hours on a slow machine and can potentially fail. Only build Qt if you really need to, for example, I use a static 64bit MinGW build, which I have no choice but to build myself since Qt doesn't provide a prebuilt one.

Comment: I have been building Qt on mac for the past 6 years, and on Windows for qt versions 4.7 to 5.2.  Since Qt 5.3 I have no need to build Qt on Windows, the pre built version was good but as WebEngine does not work with prebuilt version of Qt 5.7, the angle implementation crashes I need to build the source to add the fix given by Qt.  I don't have a license for VS2015 so i cannot change compiler, so I trying to figure out why Qt is not building with VS2013

Comment: There are free versions of VS2015 available...

Comment: No need to get visual studio, the compiler is now available standalone and for free, goes by the name of "m$ build tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

Answer (score 0):

If it somebody help :

Comment line 104 and 105:

```
// template<typename Caller, typename NodeType>
// using DestructionFunction = void (Caller::*)(NodeType *);
```

Change line 108 from:

```
void registerDestructionHelper(NodeType *, DestructionFunction, PropertyType);
```

to:

```
void registerDestructionHelper(NodeType *, void (Caller::*)(NodeType *), PropertyType);
```

line 111 from:

```
void registerDestructionHelper(NodeType *node, DestructionFunction<Caller, NodeType> func, NodeType *&)
```

to :

```
void registerDestructionHelper(NodeType *node, void (Caller::*func)(NodeType *), NodeType *&)
```

line 119 from:

```
void registerDestructionHelper(NodeType *node, DestructionFunction<Caller, NodeType> func, QVector<NodeType*> &)
```

to :

```
void registerDestructionHelper(NodeType *node, void (Caller::*func)(NodeType *), QVector<NodeType*> &)
```